# Documents not getting deleted in Mongo after using expiresAfterSecond

Tags: mongodb, ttl

I am playing around with MongoDB ttl feature. I created a sample collection (expiryTrial) and inserted a sample document as follows.

```js
db.expiryTrial.insert({"createdAt": new Date(), "key":"value"})
```

Next, i created an index and gave an expiry time as shown below

```js
db.expiryTrial.ensureIndex({"createdAt": 1}, {expireAfterSeconds: 60})
```

But I don't see the document deleted after the time passed. I know it might take some more time after the expected because the ttl thread runs every 60 secs. But even after leaving the documents for 5-6 mins, they are still there. Following are some more details which might be useful.

I checked if the ttl monitor is still active using the following command

```js
db.adminCommand({getParameter:1, ttlMonitorSleepSecs: 1});
```

Output:-

```js
{ "ttlMonitorSleepSecs" : 60, "ok" : 1 }
```

I checked if the indexes are created or not using the following command

```js
db.expiryTrial.getIndexes()
```

output:-

```js
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "test.expiryTrial"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "createdAt" : 1
                },
                "name" : "createdAt_1",
                "ns" : "test.expiryTrial",
                "expireAfterSeconds" : 30
        }
]
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on the information provided so far there doesn't seem to be any obvious reason this shouldn't work. Can you confirm the specific version of MongoDB you are using (`db.version()` in the `mongo` shell)? I would also double check that the test document you inserted is definitely in the same database & collection that has the TTL index. If you want to confirm the TTL thread actually runs, there's a counter in serverStatus metrics which should be incremented on each pass: `db.serverStatus().metrics.ttl.passes`.

Comment: @Stennie. I am using Mongo Enterprise version 3.4.6. I also checked the database as well as the collection name. Everything was alright. Although the issue is resolved as of now. I used a new dbpath while starting MongoDB. And tried the same thing again. This time it worked. I guess the older files were messing with the functionality.  Thanks anyway

Comment: "Older files messing with the functionality" doesn't sound like a plausible explanation but sounds like all is working as expected for you now ;-). Common TTL issues are mismatch in the field name (index vs document) or indexed field that does not include a BSON Date value.